# Re-initializing a global array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, global

I have a struct `type` and I want to initialize a global array of pointers to this. 
So I did `static block_t *list_array[9] = {NULL};` to declare and initialise it to null as well.

The program is expected to be called repeatedly, which means the global variables have to be re-initialized, so when I set `static block_t *list_array[9] = {NULL};` again in the initialization function, I got a compiler warning saying "Unused variable" so I couldn't figure out what the issue is.

So I tried looping through the array and setting each one of them to `NULL` like so -

```c
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        list_array[i] = NULL;
    }
```

Now the problem is that within the scope of the initialization function, this works fine but when I try to access this list_array in another function it gives an error saying `cannot access memory at ....`

The declaration is at the file level and I am trying to access it within the same file itself.

```c
static block_t *list_array[9] = {NULL};

bool mm_init(void) {
 /* some code has been removed because not relevant*/
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        list_array[i] = NULL;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now when I try to access `list_array[i]` in another function, like

```
static block_t *find_bucket(size_t bucket_size) {
    block_t *free_start;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        if (bucket_size <= (size_t)buckets[i]) {
            free_start = list_array[i];
            return free_start;
        }
    }

    free_start = list_array[8];
    return free_start;
}
```

I stepped through with a debugger and when i tried `p list_array[0]` it gave me an error saying `cannot access memory at 0x0` but if i did the same in `mm_init` then it prints `(block_t*) 0x0`

Comment: You're missing some important information:  (1) Where is your declaration?  At the file level?  Inside a function?  (2) Where are you trying to access it from?  The same file?  A different file?  A different function?  The problem cannot be reproduced from the information you posted.

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If `list_array` is global, then it doesn't need to be `static` as its storage duration is for the life of the program and since it is an array type, it can be initialized.

Comment: Re *"when I set `static block_t *list_array[9] = {NULL};` **again** in the initialization..."* Does that mean you have defined another array in another block scope, so it is shadowing the first one? You can only define one instance of a variable once.

Comment: I have added some more information and detail, also I understand what you are saying about shadowing, but if I want to re-initialize a global thing how would I do it?

Comment: Use `memset` or a loop?

Comment: Well the array contains pointers, each with a value `NULL` so that could be why you get the message `cannot access memory at 0x0`. You can only access memory from a pointer value that locates an **allocated** memory region of some kind. `NULL` is used to show the pointer does not point "anywhere". It is a place holder intended to tell you that, whereas you can't tell from some random value whether or not it points to a valid location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        list_array[i] = NULL;
    }
```

this worked .